# Shapes in OpenGL not properly set behind others

Tags: cocoa, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am drawing a simple quad in OpenGL at "altitude" y=0.3, and after another quad below this one at altitude y=0 and in another color.

However when being above with the camera or turning around, the quad below appears above the higher one.

Is a 0.3 altitude too low for OpenGL or has this to do in the order they are drawn ?
I have read that I could enable glEnable(DEPTH_TEST), but my Cocoa/Xcode environment does not know DEPTH_TEST.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: it's glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have read right. You dont have the z-buffer enabled. To do this, you need to do glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST).

[documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml)

Comment: Thanks, the command is recognized now. But should I simply put it at the beginning of the code, of does it require me do perform other things specifically ?

Comment: Just put it at the beginning.

Comment: I did it, but my below object is still appearing above the higher object. What did I wrong ?

Comment: Just found that I could enable the depth buffer within the Interface Builder of Xcode (24 bits). However the quality of my lines became awful from far distance when they were smooth before, any idea how I could fine-tune this ? Thanks !

Comment: Line smoothing doesn't work with depth testing, you'll have to look into depth sorting for that (rendering the farthest line first)

Comment: Thanks. I just found that I could retrieve a good quality by increaing the near value in my glPerspective function (was at 0.01 and set it to 1).